# Display custom error message in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: error-handling, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, custom-error-handling

I'm new in AX and want to know how to display custom error message or warning. I have looked for the solution and found out following in an *msdn* link;

> You can optionally display a custom error message in a dialog of the Web application by having your plug-in throw an **InvalidPluginExecutionException** exception with the custom message as the Message property value.

But I have no idea how to use it.

can [this link](http://kamalblogs.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/creating-a-custom-compiler-output-type-and-displaying-in-the-compiler-output-in-dynamics-ax-2009/) be helpful in achieving this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning and error messages in AX are handled by the Infolog system. From X++, you use the [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.info.aspx), [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.warning.aspx), or [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.error.aspx) methods to add a message to the Infolog. Typically, you would throw the return value from those methods to also generate an exception:

```
throw error("My error message.");
```

On Enterprise Portal pages, most pages will have an Infolog webpart. You can add messages to the Infolog using the Info object from the .NET Business Connector proxy. See the topic [Using the Infolog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc606908.aspx) in MSDN.